# How would I be able to create a routing table lookup in C?

Tags: c, routes, ip, ip-address, packets

The assignment requires that you design a router table lookup routine that will take a destination IP address from a simulated frame (actually the packet within the simulated frame) and  then executes a search of a routing table (keep it simple say a 2 x 2 array with one column being the known IP addresses and one being the port in the simulated box where you will direct packets bound for this IP towards).

I've been working on this for awhile and i'm stuck. Can someone help me! I've created a text file and tried to insert it in the the project but it still does not detect it. I don't know what else to do. Thanks in advance!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

void Ouccpy_Routing_Table();

typedef struct RTE
{
unsigned long Dest;
int port;
unsigned long Route;
};



Route[120]; 
struct IP
{
unsigned char Ipverison;
unsigned char TOS;
unsigned short ID;
unsigned short Fragoffset;
unsigned char TTL;
unsigned char Protcl;
unsigned char dcheksum;
unsigned char Data[1];

};

int main()
{
int count;

FILE *ptr_testfile;

struct IP my_testfile;

ptr_testfile = fopen_s("c:\\testroute\\TEST.txt", "rb");

if (!ptr_testfile)
{
    printf("Cannot Open File!");

    return 1;
}

while (count = 2) count <= (sizeof(struct IP)); count++;
{

    fread(&my_testfile, sizeof(struct IP), 2, ptr_testfile);

}

fclose(ptr_testfile);

return 0;
}

void Ouccpy_Routing_Table()
{

}
```

Comment: You are aware the `while`-loop does *not* loop around the `fread()`?

Comment: This line `while (count = 2) count <= (sizeof(struct IP)); count++;` does not seem to make any sense.

Comment: I wasn't sure! Should I replace it with for instead of while? I'm confused by that line also. when I was putting it into Visual studio it didn't make sense to me, but I wasn't sure if I was right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Put the text file in the corresponsing location.

- c:\testroute\TEST.txt

Verify it before compiling. If the problem persists, please post the error code?

Comment: There were no errors, but when I debug it. File still does not show up. Did I not put the file in the correct location?

Comment: - You are opening the file only in in read binary mode.
- File will be created only if you open in write mode and if you write something.
Please, navigate the C->testroute directory and make sure you its available if its all about reading.

Comment: @jeffy i'm confused as to what you explaining.I currently changed it too ptr_testfile = fopen(":C\\testroute\TEST.txt", "r");. I added the test route to the resource files tab. Yes it all about reading the file.

Comment: Please make sure you have typed the file absolute path correctly.
Its fopen("C:\\testroute\\TEST.txt", "r"); 
Provided, there is a file named TEST.txt under testroute directory in C drive.

Comment: I fixed the incorrect path, when I debug the program I don't get the cannot open file.

Comment: Then the file is opened correctly. Make sure your file has contents in it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the way the code tries to open the file

```
ptr_testfile = fopen_s("c:\\testroute\\TEST.txt", "rb");
```

The compiler should at least warn you not providing enough parameters.

If you would have read the [documentation to `fread_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx) you would have learned that it should have been called:

```
errno_t en = fopen_s(&ptr_testfile, "c:\\testroute\\TEST.txt", "rb");
if (0 != en)
{
   issue some error message here
}
```

As an alternative you could use the standard `fopen()` instead the Microsoft specific `fopen_s()`. `fopen()` would be called as your original code does.

---

This

```
while (count = 2) count <= (sizeof(struct IP)); count++;
{
  fread(...);
}
```

is the same as

```
while (count = 2) 
  count <= (sizeof(struct IP)); 

count++;

{
  fread(...);
}
```

which in turn is the same as

```
while (count = 2) /* This repeatly assigns 2 to count. Resulting in an infinite loop.*/
{
  count <= sizeof(struct IP); /* This does nothing. */
}

/* Because of the infinite loop above the code never arrives here. */

count++; 

fread(...);
```

Please have a second look.

Comment: Alright, I still don't understand, but I will try!! thanks

Comment: ohhhh... alright. @alk So if I change the while loop to a for loop it would only assign the 2 to count instead of the constantly repeating it?

Comment: @DerJude: This definitely depends on how creative you'd be with this "change" ...;-)